# More than one groupBox at the same location

Tags: c#, groupbox

I have an application with 4 groupBox at the same location on the screen and I need to let the usere "to see" only one ot them by selecting with radio button.

I wrote `groupBox.Visible = true;`

But it works ONLY for the first two groupBox. The third and fourth are not displayed. 
Is there a "limit" to the number of the groupBox I can place to the same location?

If I place the third and the fourth groupBox in a different location on the screen, it works!

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you add some code showing how you're doing it? And are you sure that you're only having one group box visible at each time? Just so that one of them doesn't appear underneath another one..

Comment: No limit.  Problem is in your code, which you didn't show us.